# A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Development. I'm trying to make a new tabbed activity, but whenever I run this, the app immediately crashes. It doesn't run on both my phone and my emulator. What is going on?

Here's the error I get:

```
1676-1685/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
```

and then followed by a bunch of stack traces. Here is one of them:

```
1676-1685/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:170)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:190)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1142)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:267)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
        at com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider.computeLocalDigestAndUpdateValues(GservicesProvider.java:450)
        at com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider.onCreate(GservicesProvider.java:185)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1686)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1655)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4964)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4559)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4499)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What am I supposed to close? I've barely changed the original code that Android Studio generated for me, but it's still telling me there is some resource leak.

Here's what is in my main activity java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    actionBar.addTab(
            actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(0))
                .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(
            actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(1))
                    .setTabListener(this));
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return CardListFragment.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class CardListFragment extends Fragment{

    public static CardListFragment newInstance(){
        CardListFragment fragment = new CardListFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public CardListFragment(){
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Please help! I'm still trying to learn this whole concept of fragment.

Comment: Can you post one of the stack traces please?

Comment: Yes, added to original post

Comment: Do you have any other activities or code that uses SQLite?

Comment: No, which is the strange part. There's nowhere where I use anything with SQLite